# Why has my computer's performance decreased after installing a significantly better CPU, and how do I fix it?

Tags: cpu, performance, intel-core-i7

Earlier today, I replaced my computer's i3 8100 with an i7 9700k. The computer wouldn't start until I updated BIOS so I did, to the latest version.

Now my computer actually works, but my performance in CS:GO is a lot worse, often dropping below 100 FPS when before it was always above 150 and giving me texture bugs where certain textures are super low-res or just a placeholder shiny black texture.

Also the fan keeps going mad when before I would rarely ever hear it.

Is there a way how I can fix this?

Comment: A cooling problem with the new cpu?

Comment: Did you replace thermal compound and clean the heatsink aassembly when refitting it?

Comment: ok i will add more thermal paste and clean the heatsink assembly also the fan is backwards for some reason but it was like that with my last processor and it worked fine...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like CPU is overheating and throttling.

i7 produces more heat than i3, make sure your cpu cooler is of adequate power/size, clean and is installed correctly (with a proper amount of thermal grease - not too much, not too little etc.) Also check that your case is able to take out all the hot air from the cooler (and also GPU).